# Saronno: what platform for MXP?

Tags: trains, italy, trenitalia, mxp

Going from Saronno station (near Milan) to Malpensa airport (MXP) on train number 325 departing 10:16, what platform (at Saronno) does the train depart from?

We have only 5 minutes to make the connection from Como, with kids and bags in tow, so it would be useful to know the platform number in advance. Date is tomorrow Friday 3 June 2016 (if it makes a difference).

We've looked on the Trenitalia website and can't find this info.

Comment: Question is too specific. You should **always** check the platform when at the station, or ask the train guard on your previous train (they all have smartphones). While *a lot* of track routes are built so that only a single platform can serve a certain destination (a single platform of failure for the line), in the majority of cases the traffic controller may redirect the train to another platform and then divert back the swaps to the correct path

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the platform from which a particular train departed on some day in July 2016 will never be of interest to anybody ever again.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the platform from which trains depart are often subject to change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have data on your phone, I highly recommend the trenit app for [android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.baroncelli.oraritrenitalia) or [iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/it/app/trenit!-orari-ritardi-prezzi/id1058908183?mt=8). It gives you the train times in real-time updated after every station. Usually it tells you the platform but doesn't seem to be giving that for Saronno at the moment. The app is showing the train tomorrow as the 329 at 10:16 rather than the 325. If you miss it there's one just 8 minutes later.

[Saronno station](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stazione_di_Saronno) isn't very large and from the information on that page it looks like you go to MXP from platform 5/6.

Comment: Good luck. But if you're setting off now, doesn't that mean you're getting the 9:16 from Saronno which is the 325 as you originally mentioned?

Comment: We were just super- early for the train from Como Lago. :)

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be platform 6.

Going in the other direction, the train to Como Lago from Saronno leaves from platform 2.

Comment: Glad you made it. At the airport 3 hours early then?